# Xcode log after application being Archive

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, deployment, app-store

Is there any possible to get `Xcode` logs after application being `Archived`? I know there is a log for build process but I want to check the package preapering process for `App Store`.

I want to validate my own package build proccess. I'm using Qt to create MacOS application and After creating `Info.plist` and `*.entitlements` files there is still missing some metadata.